# Does a SATA III controller for PCI-e 1.0 (x16) exist?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, streaming

I'm trying to hunt around for a solution to a disk issue I have with my home server.  Basically, I started to use it to stream video (going from a virtual host, it now does alot more).  I see alot of lag and I am fairly sure it's my motherboard's SATA output.  The 2 drives I have storing the video are RAID 0 SATA II drives on SATA 1 ports.  I'd like to upgrade these drives to 2TB SATA III drives, but I need a solution.

My motherboard is an [Intel D975XBX2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813121059)

It has a Radeon x1900 (old card), Q6600 (old quad core), 8GB ram, and 5 drives at the moment.  I am tryng not to rebuild.

Any suggestions on how to increase the I/O keeping in mind that this is also a storage server, domain controller, virtual server (hyper-v), running W2k8R2?

Comment: Your mobo has SATA II ports, not "SATA 1".  Before you spend money & time on an upgrade that might produce little or no improvement, you should confirm your premise that the issue is the "SATA output".  How fast is the RAM (i.e. is the FSB running at 1066 or only 800MHz to constrain the I/O bandwidth)? Run memtest86+ to get RAM speed.  What exactly is "a lot of lag" in regards to stream video?  Is the W2k OS and other software capable of maximizing the throughput of your hardware?

Comment: Not sure why you need that many lanes. . .

Comment: Considering the full potential of Sata II, I doubt you'd see videos stutter.  Unless they have a bitrate of 20 gagillion.

Answer (score 0):

If the Virtual Server is running on the same drive as the domain controller andyou then have two (or more ) OSs running on one physical drive(s) you will have disk I/O issues.  If you can place the VM on a different physical drive, even an external, you should see better performance.  I use an eSATA external to isolate a VM but USB 3.0 would be a good choice now.

As a test, can you shut down the VM and see what happens to performance.